# Retrieve data based on date from excel with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

hello all I'm stuck in the following steps using Python and Pandas. I'm trying to retrieve the country with the most goals in "FIFA" matches since 2010.

[excel sheet picture][1]

Below is a piece of code and not sure if it's alright since I'm still learning.

```
#Which country has scored the most goals in FIFA events (qualifiers, 
#cups, etc.) since 2010? 


# convert to datetime format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# to get the most goals by sum
df['total_score'] = df['home_score'] + df['away_score']  


#Not sure how to check all data as long as theres the word FIFA in it?
sub_df = df[ (df['tournament'] == "FIFA") & (df['neutral'] != "True") ] 

#Not sure how to check all data as long as theres the word FIFA in it?
sub_df = df[(df['tournament'] == "FIFA") & (df['date'].dt.year >= 2010)]

# to get maximum total_score
sub_df2 = sub_df[sub_df['total_score'] == sub_df['total_score'].max()]  

print(sub_df2)

**Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score, 
tournament, city, country, neutral, total_score]
Index: []**
```

**EDIT: Updated code but not sure how to return the Country with most goals**

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%M/%D')

# to get the most goals by sum
df['total_score'] = df['home_score'] + df['away_score']  

#to get data only from year 2010 and up and events that have the word 
#FIFA in it
sub_df = df[(df['date'].dt.year >= 2010) & 
(df['tournament'].str.contains('FIFA'))]

#Which country has scored the most goals in FIFA events (qualifiers, 
#cups,  etc.) since 2010? 
sub_df2 = sub_df[sub_df['total_score'] == sub_df['total_score'].max()]

#print the return value of the country with most goals
print(sub_df2)
print(sub_df2['country'], sub_df2['total_score'].max())
print("The country that has scored the most goals in FIFA events is: ")`
```

This is what is being returned:
[enter image description here][1]

**I want to return the country with the most goals scored in all FIFA events**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxONa.png

Comment: `sub_df = df[(df['tournament'] == "Friendly") & (df['neutral'] != 'TRUE')]`?

Comment: You assigned a value to 'sub_df' two times, so that first assignment to 'sub_df' is overwritten by second assignment. Is this what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

I provided a sample data by considering your original posting:

```
         date home_team away_team  home_score  away_score tournament     city   country neutral
0  2011-11-30  Scotland   England           0           0       FIFA  Glasgow  Scotland   FALSE
1  2012-03-08   England  Scotland           4           2       FIFA   London   England   FALSE
2  2010-03-07  Scotland   England           2           1       FIFA  Glasgow  Scotland   FALSE
3  2009-03-06   England  Scotland           2           2   Friendly   London   England   FALSE
4  2010-04-03  Scotland   England           3           0       FIFA  Glasgow  Scotland   FALSE
5  2009-03-25  Scotland     Wales           4           0   Friendly  Glasgow  Scotland   FALSE
```

Your code is basically OK. I just changed a datetime format and a print format at the very beginning and end.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d') # format shoud be matched with your data

# to get the most goals by sum
df['total_score'] = df['home_score'] + df['away_score']

#to get data only from year 2010 and up and events that have the word FIFA in it
sub_df = df[(df['date'].dt.year >= 2010) & (df['tournament'].str.contains('FIFA'))]

#Which country has scored the most goals in FIFA events (qualifiers, cups, etc.) since 2010
sub_df2 = sub_df[sub_df['total_score'] == sub_df['total_score'].max()]

#print the return value of the country with most goals. 
print("The country that has scored the most goals in FIFA events is: ")
print(sub_df2['country'].iloc[0], sub_df2['total_score'].iloc[0])
```

This code will print:

```
The country that has scored the most goals in FIFA events is: 
England 6
```

Comment: thanks I've updated the code with your suggestions. however, the return value i get is "empty dataframe" any ideas why?

Comment: In your recently edited code, It seems that there is no data, which year value is greater than 2010, right? @user3042226

Comment: yes correct I want to look for year value greater than 2010. I do have data on my excel. Any ideas? @Sangkeun Park

Comment: @user3042226 Then, it would be helpful if you update current data so that people can try it.

Comment: yes, I have posted the new data on top, thanks

Comment: @user3042226 I just edied my answer. I provided a sample data and I showed how it works with a full code.

Comment: what exactly is the use of using iloc[0] ? thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @user3042226 It is to get first row and pick the specific values. If you don't speficify first row like that, it will print dataframe including Name, dtype ... as you can see the result in the picture you uploaded.